# Setting root page in ionic2 and angular2 app based on an asynchronous event

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm trying to start a basic ionic2 app and was wondering if my timing of initial app loading is a problem or not.  What I'd like to do is set the start page to a login page if the user is not authenticated.

I originally set the rootpage to the home page and then when the async call came back from localstorage, I would then reset the rootpage to the login page if the user was unauthenticated.  However, this caused a flickering where they see one page and then get sent to another page.

It seems like what I want to do is wait for the local storage call before I show any screen.

My question is this: as the code stands now, will there be an error condition where the platform ready fires before the root page is set, thus causing some sort of problem?  How should I handle this situation in Ionic 2 and Angular 2?  Should I make the get localStorage call synchronous, or should I stuff it in another event or method that is part of the app or page lifecycle in Angular 2?

Should I use some sort of observable or await syntax?

```
export class MyApp {
  rootPage: any;
  local: Storage = new Storage(LocalStorage);

  constructor(platform: Platform) {

    this.local.get('user').then(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.rootPage = TabsPage;
      } else {
        this.rootPage = LoginPage;
      }
    });

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Will this ever fire before the rootpage is set?
      StatusBar.styleDefault();

    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add asynchronous call to the local storage as you can see in this example: 
https://github.com/RedFroggy/ionic2-nfc-app/blob/master/app/app.ts#L52

You just need to check the user existence in the local storage and set the rootPage to the HomePage or LoginPage.

Comment: Also while checking this thing you can have the splashscreen open and manually hide it after the operation is done so the user wont know what is happening instead of using dummy initial page like the answer below

Comment: The problem is Ionic bug...when dynamically change rootPage the constructor of page would be called twice, in this case `MainPage` would be called twice...

Answer (score 2):

You could create dummy initial page (i.e. white background, preloader whatever) to avoid flickering and then switch to login or tabs page.

Comment: just manually hide the splashscreen instead of having a dummy page (I guess that this operation is done on start of the app). Also instead of local storage I just write the ID of the user in txt file. If it exists log him in and show homepage, if it doesnt show login page